# In bash, how can I erase an alias without logout?

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc, shell-builtin

I had an alias in my `.bashrc` and I really don't want it anymore. I erased the `alias`, but my bash already has this alias loaded.

Can I erase this `alias` from this bash without logging out?

Comment: For questions like these, try Google next time. It works.

Comment: I did... didn't work

Comment: Oh ... I tried searching on Google using keywords from your question: `erase alias bash`. It worked. Not a big deal, just a humble suggestion.

Comment: @mtahmed good for you! Even being not a hard question, this it is a positive thing to the community because now those keywords will most likely end up here. I tried `erase alias bash without logout` ftw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by using `unalias`:

```
[zak ~]$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
[zak ~]$ unalias ls
[zak ~]$ alias ls
bash: alias: ls: not found
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `unalias` command:

```
$ alias foo=ls
$ foo
... ls output ...
$ unalias foo
$ foo
bash: foo: command not found
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have many aliases and wish to clear them all, run `unalias -a`. Then you can source your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases`) file to use the aliases there.

```
$ unalias -a
$ # '.' is like an alias to 'source'
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Sometimes it is desirable to disable an alias temporarily instead of unaliasing it entirely. To do this, put a `\` in front of your command.

```
$ alias foo=ls
$ foo
... ls output ...
$ \foo
bash: foo: command not found
$ foo
... ls output ...
```